# In Haskell, how to generate an arbitrary number of mutable variables and put them in a vector?

Tags: haskell

Lets say I wanted to make 4 mutable arrays then later access them and mutate them based on their index of a vector :

```
 fn = do $
     v1 <- newMArray (Sz1 1) 0
     v2 <- newMArray (Sz1 1) 0
     v3 <- newMArray (Sz1 1) 0
     v4 <- newMArray (Sz1 1) 0
     let vls = Data.Vector.fromList [v1,v2,v3,v4]
     loopM 0 (<= 3) (+1) (\k -> modifyM_ (vls ! k) (+1) 0)
```

Now how would I generate N number of mutable arrays simply by supplying an integer N as an argument to `fn`?

Comment: It looks to me like you want `replicateM`, but the question is a bit vague.

Comment: @dfeuer Would each mutable array generated in the vector be a unique MArray using replicateM such that if i mutated one using modifyM_ at a single index it would be different from the rest of the MArrays in the vector?

Comment: Yes. `replicateM n (newMArray (Sz1 1) 0)` will produce `n` separate mutable arrays.

Comment: Thank you! this answers my question then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`generateM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.3.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:generateM) will get you where you need to go.

```
generateM 4 (\_ -> newMArray (Sz1 1) 0)
```

Comment: Yes, that's better.